# System hangs on shutdown/reboot - stoping User Manager for UID 1000

Tags: systemd, shutdown, plasma5

I'm having this issue when shutting down for a while now. When I shutdown or reboot system I've got 17 jobs which hangs shutting down for 90 seconds.

- 16 of them are related to LVM
- 1 says Stopping User Manager for UID 1000

I found one post that suggested to first logout from user session and login as other user and check if there is something still running for main user.

I checked that by logging out, switching to console (CTRL + ALT + F1) and logging in as root and executing command:

```
systemd-cgls
```

For user-1000.slice node there were 2 processes running: baloo_file and plasmashell.

Now I'm not sure what can I do with that information, so I'm asking here for help.

I'm using openSUSE Leap 42.3 4.4.114-42-default with plasma 5.12 but I had this problem with plasma 5.8 too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just [disable baloo](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=193169) file indexer and you are good to go.

```
$ balooctl disable
Disabling the File Indexer
```

It may sound really drastic, and it is. I had no good experiences with KDE5(specially with this file indexer), and every time i've tried it again, baloo has making my CPU hang(an AMD FX-9370), or was doing this kind of poweroff blocking as you are facing. Not to sound like a moron that lives in the past, but when KDE4 was pretty stable they started this journey with this unfinnished endless buggy environment that is KDE5.

If you Google "baloo file", you will see that there is a lot of folks complaining about this tool eating resources or blocking access to them.

Comment: Seems that was enough to help. Just to be sure, I've read that File Indexer is useless when using SSD. Is that right?